# How do I make UseEffect hook run step by step and not last?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have UseEffect hook that fetches data from DB and I want it to run FIRST in my component, but it runs last.

How do I make it run before "console.log(titleee)"?

Code:

```
 const [cPost, setCPost] = useState([]);
  const postId = id.match.params.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts/'+postId)
      .then(posts => {
        setCPost(posts.data);
        console.log("test");
      })
  }, []);



const titleee = cPost.title;
console.log(titleee);
```

Comment: useEffect fires after layout and paint. You might be after useLayoutEffect instead as it comes in earlier

Comment: axios call is async and you can't control when it should resolve, this code is working as expected. If you want, you can delay the execution of the block using setTimeout() but not guaranteed to work as you expected because of event loop and asynchronous nature of the JS.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't think that's the correct path that you want to take.**

In order to show the `cPost` on your page after the request `/posts/+postId` finished you can opt-out for two following options.

You can show a "loader" to the user if the `cPost` data is crucial for your whole component.

```
const [fetchingCPost, setFetchingCPost] = useState(false)
const [cPost, setCPost] = useState({});
const postId = id.match.params.id;

useEffect(() => {
  setFetchingCPost(true)
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts/'+postId)
    .then(posts => {
      setFetchingCPost(false)
      setCPost(posts.data);
  })
}, []);

return fetchingCPost && <div>Loading</div>
```

Or you can have some default values set from the start for `cPost`. Just to make sure that your code doesn't break. I think the first solution might be more UX acceptable.

```
const [cPost, setCPost] = useState({title: '', description: ''});
```

If you want to store `title` as a separate variable you can use `useMemo` for instance or do it via `useState` same as with `cPost`. But even then you **can't "create" it after the request finishes, you can simply change its value**.

In case you want to use `useMemo` you can make it dependent on your `cPost`.

```
const cPostTitle = useMemo(() => {
  return !!cPost.title ? cPost.title : ''
}, [cPost])
```

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean, but what if I wanted to create ```useState``` hook with value of ```cPost.title``` (that I get from DB) : ```const [title, setTitle] = useState(cPost.title);```

Comment: You use `useMemo` for that, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change you'r way of thinking when programming in react. It is important to know how react works. React does not support imperative programming, it rather support declarative and top down approach , in which case you have to declare your markup and feed it with you'r data then the only way markup changes is by means of changing you'r data. So in you'r case you are declaring a watched variable using useState hook  `const [cPost, setCPost] = useState([]);` , this variable (cPost) has initial values of `[]` then react continues rendering you'r markup using initial value, to update the rendered title to something you get from a network request (eg: a rest API call) you use another hook which is called after you'r component is rendered (useEffect). Here you have chance to fetch data and update you'r state. To do so you did as following :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts/'+postId)
      .then(posts => {
        setCPost(posts.data);
      })
  }, []);
```

this code results in a second render because part of data is changes. Here react engine goes ahead and repaint you'r markup according data change.

If you check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-platform-sysy8?file=/src/App.js) you'll see two console logs , in first render title is undefined in second render it's something we got from network.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding async/await and see if it works. Here is the link btw for your reference https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-use-async-function-in-react-hook-useeffect-typescript-js-6204a788a435